# Can I change the category of my app at iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I added many versions of my app at appstore with Utilities as a primary category ,but now I want to add it as Lifestyle category.Can I change this category with out deleting the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should be able to update the category choices you initially chose during the submission process by logging into iTunes Connect and editing your app.**

1. Log in to iTunes Connect.
2. Go to "Manage Your Applications"
3. Select your app.
4. Modify the "Primary Category".

It's unclear if you have already tried this. I haven't personally tried this in a couple of days, so I'm not sure if this functionality has been randomly removed, but it's certainly worth trying if you haven't already.

You can also change the category when submitting an update to your application, so if all else fails, this is always an option.

Comment: Basically I want to add new version of App,When I click on app and click on meta data ,there is no option for edition primary category ,it only shows utility

Comment: this used to be allowed, and is no longer allowed. You can't submit the same binary either, as it checks the binary version and won't let you upload the same version number.

Comment: @Brad: If it's no longer allowed, you should post a new answer and I'll remove mine! Or you can edit this one to update the information. People aren't likely to see it in a comment.

Answer (score 12):

Create a new version of the application and submit the binary again. While creating new version we can change the primary and secondary categories.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it is to submit a new version in iTunesConnect. If you are fortunate and haven't deleted the old binary, simply resubmit it. If you are out of luck like me then you will need to submit a new release. (Reason why I say out of luck is...I am 1/2 way down into the development of my next release and it is no shape to be submitted to appstore which means a month delay for me to just change the category)

Answer (score 2):

First select the app by going to

- iTunes Connect>My Apps> YourApp
- Under iOS APP> click Rating [edit] link.

If you have selected "Made for kids" and has already been rejected due to outbound links then there are few ways to go about this.

Option 1: Removing outgoing internet access items (links, in-app purchases etc.) and resubmit the app.

Option 2: Fix outgoing access as per Apple guidelines (which may include adding verbiage to seek help from parents/adults). So redesign and resubmit the app. Apple guideline: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/parental-gates/

Option 3: Uncheck Made for kids option. To do this you will have to delete the binary.Then Re-add the app icon(1024x1024), upload build and resubmit.